# Sequelize Tables not Associated Issue

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am running into an issue where I am trying to populate a value for multiple tables in one route POST method. I read the section in the documentation for creation with associations and mimicked the example, but I get an issue:

```
Error: organization is not associated to user!
    at validateIncludedElement (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:560:11)
```

I am not sure why this is happening since I am using the `.belongsTo` method that should create the association.

Here is the User.js model:

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    organizationName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'organization_name',
        unique: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    freezeTableName: true
},{
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            User.belongsTo(db.Organization)
        }
    }
});
    return User;
}
```

Here is the organization.js model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    organizationName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'organization_name'
    },
    admin: DataTypes.STRING,
    members: DataTypes.STRING
});

    return Organization;
}
```

Here is the model index file where the tables are attached to a db object db-index.js:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var path = require('path');
var config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/config.js'));
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
});

var db = {}

db.Organization = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/organization");

db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");

db.Annotation = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/annotation");


db.Annotation.associate(db);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

Here are the routes (`/sign-up` is where I am making the reference):

```
var express = require('express');
var siteRoutes  = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');

/*====  Passport Configuration  ====*/

// Serialize sessions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log(user.user_id + "Serializing");
  done(null, user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
  models.User.find({where: {user_id: user_id}}).then(function(user){
    done(null, user);
  }).error(function(err){
    done(err, null);
  });
});


passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true,
    usernameField: 'email'
    }, 
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        //Find user by email
        models.User.findOne({
            where: { 
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
            }
        }).then(function(user) {
            return done(null, user);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Email not found.'));
        });
    }
    ));




/*====  Index   ====*/

siteRoutes.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index.hbs');
});

/*====  Login   ====*/


siteRoutes.route('/login')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/login.hbs');
    })

    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/app',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'
    }));



siteRoutes.route('/sign-up')

    .get(function(req, res){
        res.render('pages/sign-up.hbs');
    })

    .post(function(req, res){

        models.User.create({
            Organization: {
                organizationName: req.body.organizationName
            },
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        },{include: [models.Organization]}).then(function() { 
        res.redirect('/');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
    })

});







module.exports = siteRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only associate model annotation

```
db.Annotation.associate(db);
```

forget

```
db.User.associate(db);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing out an obvious flaw, but I get a new error after adding that snippet: `db.User.associate(db);
        ^
TypeError: Object [object SequelizeModel:user] has no method 'associate'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/synotate/app/models/db-index.js:26:9)`

Comment: I figured out why the second issue was occurring. In my model I am adding an additional condition that sequelize is not recognizing as the options section of my object. After I remove the {} for the classMethods section I did not receive the error.